# Set Equal Distance Between Layers (PS)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

How can you set multiple layers equal distance between them in Photoshop in a given distance?

I know you can do the math and manually set the x axis value for each of them, but I am looking for a simpler solution and, more importantly, faster.

**Example:**

- Input - 5 rectangles 150x150 px size; distance between the grids 1000 px:

[image]

- Do something set equal distance between rectangles `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`.
- Result:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select each layer in question (3 or more) and go to Layer > Distribute > Vertical Centers.  There are also icons along the top as shortcuts if you select the layers and have the arrow tool in use.

To contol how far, just position your first and last layer in the array andit will distribute evenly in between.

Comment: This is actually not true. It won't distribute spacing. it distributes upon **object** centers. If the objects (layers) are different widths and/or heights, nothing will be spaced "evenly". It's been requested for literally *years* that Adobe implement a "Distribute spacing" option in Photoshop, but it's just not there.

Comment: I understand that, as the name implies.  However, For this example, it is true.  The object sizes are the same.

Comment: Sorry a 1, 3 and 5 are all different widths and will not distribute on centers evenly. While the *boxes* may distribute, the text will not. Of course, you could make each box and text a smart object. None the less Photoshop still offers no way to distribute spacing evenly.

Comment: This will do, thanks. Tho, PS should really include an option where you can select multiple layers and add a numeric margin between them.

Comment: @scott Ok, we could run scenarios all day I guess; but I was just more concerned with providing a solution to this rather than excuse on why it is "not possible".  I am a 12 year veteran in this.  Please find someone else to poke holes in.